# Run migration command twice inside aliases in mix file

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

Inside the aliases in mix file. If we define migration command like this:

```
 defp aliases do
  [
    "ecto.migrate": [
      "ecto.migrate  data/priv/repo/migrations",
      "ecto.migrate --migrations-path apps/al/priv/repo/migrations"
     ]
  ]
```

If we run `mix ecto.migrate`. only first command executed and second ignored.

I know mix don’t allow run same task twice. And I don’t think `Mix.task.rerun or reenable` will work here because its not custom task.

Is there any way to override it so both commands will execute?

Comment: Of course, it’s a custom task and hence `Mix.task.rerun` would work. There is nothing special with `ecto` tasks, they are the same tasks as yours :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thanks for your suggestion. I tried `Mix.task.rerun "ecto.migrate --migration_path"`. but  it  gave `task not defined error`. Can you please kind enough to elaborate the proper way of  using  it in a answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to rerun tasks from `Mix.Project`, but you might easily create your own task to suit your needs.

```
cat lib/mix/tasks/my_migrate.ex
```

```rb
defmodule Mix.Tasks.MyApp.MyMigrate do
  @shortdoc "Executes `ecto.migrate` several times for different paths"

  use Mix.Task

  @impl Mix.Task
  def run(paths) do
    Enum.each(paths, fn path ->
      Mix.shell().info("Executing Ecto.Migrate for path: " <> path)
      Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate.run(migrations_path: path)
      Mix.Task.reenable(Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate)
    end)
  end
end
```

And run it as

```
mix my_app.my_migrate "data1/migrations" "data2/migrations"
```

Comment: Just for anyone else stuck on this, the Ecto Migrate task is obviously expecting argv, not a keyword list, so either you need a quick:

```elixir
[migrations_path: path]
|> OptionParser.to_argv()
|> Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate.run()
```

Or it's actually simpler to just call the Ecto.Migrator directly like you would in a release:

Comment: `Ecto.Migrator.run(repo, path_or_paths, :up, all: true)`